# Do the Blade Wings digital item take an equipment slot?

Tags: diablo-iii

If you purchase the Heart of the Swarm Deluxe Edition from Blizzard you receive a bonus item for your Diablo 3 character called Blade Wings.

Do these wings always show up on your character?  Are they an item (eg shoulder equipment) and if they are do they layer over normal equipment or are they just no stat items for standing around in town?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they won't take any equipment slot.

They're most likely exactly like the Collector's Edition's item.

You can right-click activate the item to apply or remove the invisible buff showing up as the angel wings. So you can activate the item, then put it back into your stash.

Every new character created starts with the item in inventory. You can trade it between your own characters using your stash and you can delete it by dropping it. So essentially all you need is to keep one copy in your stash, delete the others and you're fine.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know for certain because I do not yet have them, but I can make the educated guess that they are implemented in the same way as the angel wings you get with Diablo III Collector's Edition.

In that case, they are an item in your inventory you can right click to turn on or off the effect. They do not take up an equipment slot and are purely visual, extending out from your character's back and existing alongside other equipment art. They do not have charges; you can use them as many times as you want. They take up 1 inventory slot.

I believe the angel wings appeared in every new character's inventory automatically. I can't say if the blade wings will be similarly distributed.